# When a partition should be done for 30 to 40 columns table in postgresql having small length data in each column?

Tags: postgresql

I am working on PostgreSQL partitions and I want to create partitions and the question is that how it will work effective, like how many records per partition, I know best query plan gives good performance but still I want to know impact of data per partition for performance

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I just want a very good performance through partitions as my table has billion of records in it @FrankHeikens

Comment: Partitioning is no magic bullet for all performance issues. We have no clue how your database is used, the database scheme, your SQL, etc. etc. We use partitions because it makes a DELETE very easy and fast: DROP TABLE

Comment: I know it makes write operations fast, but I am asking in way of the read operations through partitioning

Comment: I mean how they are improved with partitions

Comment: and logically how much data should be placed in table for making even read write operations fast having 40 cols with max length 100 of any column

Comment: As Frank already mentioned: partitioning is not primarily a (query) performance optimization. It can only be used for that if your partitioning key will be included in the WHERE clause for every query (or at least for every query that should benefit from partitioning). Queries without a restriction on the partitioning key will actually be slower. But without seeing the real queries you are trying to improve this is impossible to answer.

Comment: ok got it @a_horse_with_no_name
so basically I have to include the key in every query on which I portioning the table and this will improve the performance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is described very well here

https://severalnines.com/database-blog/guide-partitioning-data-postgresql
It says

> For some hosts, 200 GB could be the right time to partition, for
> others, it may be time to partition when it hits 1TB.